# reinterpret_cast std::function* to and from void*

Tags: c++, void-pointers, std-function, reinterpret-cast

I'm suffering a segfault in a plugin when I call a std::function in it passed from the main executable, via converting it's address to/from `void*`.  I can reproduce the problem in a few self-contained lines:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    using func_t = std::function<const std::string& ()>;

    auto hn_getter = func_t{[]() {
        return "Hello";
    }};

    auto ptr = reinterpret_cast<void*>(&hn_getter);

    auto getter = reinterpret_cast<func_t*>(ptr);
    std::cout << (*getter)() << std::endl;   // Bang!

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Even though I'm casting to the original type, it's still segfaulting.  Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Although casting to `void*` would better be done with `static_cast` (for the sake of getting rid of `reinterpret_cast`), the code seems fine to me and I can't reproduce it: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c316f8e9dc1ded2

Comment: @SergeyA But it does crash with g++: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/30f84f279c2118af

Comment: @user2079303 in the given example, cast is used (and it is required to cast from void* to actual type)

Comment: @user2079303: Look at his code; he's clearly using an "Almost Always Auto" programming style.

Comment: Never return a reference to a local variable (well, unless it is static).

Comment: @NicolBolas ah. I assumed that they used auto to avoid repeating the type from the cast; not that they used a cast in order to be able to use auto. What a confusing style (in my opinion).

Comment: Questions with [mcve] are so seldom, so existence of that itself deserves +1

Comment: As an alternative, you could also just `auto hn_getter = []() { return "Hello"; };` and then `auto getter = static_cast<decltype(hn_getter)*>(ptr);`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The cause of your problem has nothing to do with cast, it's because of the function return a `const string &`. You need:

```
using func_t = std::function<const std::string ()>;
```

And as comments suggest, `const` here is useless, just:

```
using func_t = std::function<std::string ()>;
```

Comment: Eyes of an eagle!

Comment: Or just `std::function<std::string()>`

Comment: Good catch, though `const` there is not needed.

Comment: This does indeed work, though I don't know why.  The lambda returns a const char* literal, which will be implicitly converted to an rvalue `std:string`.  Even though its a temporary, because the return type is `const&` it should stay alive long enough to be printed.

Comment: @cmannett85 No. You are returning the reference of a local temporary. It will be destroyed just after lambda returns.

Comment: @cmannett85 The lifetime of a temporary is *only* extended if it is directly bound to a named local reference during its initialization. E.g. `const std::string &str = "Hello"s;`, but not e.g. on a `return`, and neither `const std::string &str = rand() > 10000 ?
 "Hello"s : "Bye"s;` (because neither temporary is *directly* bound to the reference).