# Return reference to static variable in std::function-wrapped lambda causes segfault

Tags: c++, lambda, static

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49303730/reinerpret-cast-stdfunction-to-and-from-void), I realised was having more fundamental problems with `std::function` - specifically I'm suffering segfaults when returning a reference to a static variable in lambda *but only* when the lambda is wrapped in a `std::function`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std::string_literals;

namespace
{
const auto hello = "Hello"s;
}

int main()
{
    using func_t = std::function<const std::string& ()>;

    auto lambda = []() -> const std::string& { return hello; };
    std::cout << lambda() << std::endl; // Fine

    auto func = func_t{[]() { return hello; }};
    std::cout << func() << std::endl;   // Bang!

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The [segfault only occurs on g++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f20aa161c360326), clang++ seems to be fine with both.  Which compiler is correct?  And if it is g++, why does using `std::function` not work.

I should note that the behaviour is the same whether or not `hello` is static, or local and then captured by reference or value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[]() { return hello; }` is `[]() -> std::string { return hello; }` (without reference).

Your `func` return dangling pointer of temporary (to have `const string&`).

Both compilers are correct as you invoke UB.

`auto func = func_t{lambda};` would be correct.

Comment: I think a word about `auto` (the implied return type) being deduced always as a value will tie it all up nicely for the OP. Anyway, already up-voted.

Comment: Yep, now I feel stupid.  Thanks for info regarding deduced return type using `auto` rules, I had assumed it was `decltype(auto)`/magic.